# How to use conan_cmake_run() with conan2?

Tags: c++, conan, cmakelists-options

In the conan.io 1x version, we can install package with conan_cmake_run() and conanfile.txt in the CMakelist.
[image]

However, in the new released conan2 API https://docs.conan.io/2/index.html. There is even no such function. Is there a way in conan2 to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Hope to find something similar to conan_cmake_run(CONANFILE conanfile.txt) in conan2.

Comment: Please read the text in https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan README. There is a warning explaining the situation. Work is being done to provide this functionality (or equivalent) in 2.0, but it will take a bit